# Terraform script to disable multiple functions in Azure Function app

Tags: terraform, azure-functions, azure-powershell, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to know how to disable functions in Azure Function app using terraform script.

I have list of function code in a directory and I would like to call those functions from that directory and disable the functions in Azure Function app. Also I need to disable few functions in one environment and keep it enabled remaining functions. How to achieve this?

I have gone through multiple ways but not sure how to implement.
I went through terraform documentation, also PowerShell script but not sure how to implement this using terraform as I never found using terraform. Also I am expecting few functions should be disabled in one environment and remaining few should be enabled as it is earlier. Also all functions should be disabled in other environment. I am looking for terraform script to achieve this.

Appreciate if someone could help with the script. Also, I am new to Azure Functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally wrote the script by myself in Powershell and Bash script to enable/disable functions from the Azure functionapp and azure function app slots. Below are the two versions. Now, the below script I am executing through terraform null resoruce. The script will meet the below scenarios. So it will not directly possible via terraform instead we need to execute bash/powershell script to enable/disable azure functions and call this script via terraform null resource.

1. Enable/disable functions from functionapp main slot and funcion app preprod/any
   slot.
2. If any function you provide in the Disable_function list then those functions
   only will be disabled and remaining all other functions which are in the
   functionapp will be enabled.
3. If no functions are provided in the disable_function list then it will not
   perform any action/ it will maintain the same old state in the function app for
   the functions.
4. If any typo or misspelled function names listed in the Disabled_function list
   then it will throw error saying that function does not exist.

**Bash Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Access environment variables passed from Terraform
subscription_id="$subscription_id"
resourceGroupName="$resourceGroupname"
functionAppName="$functionappname"
deployment_slot="$deployment_slot"

# Function to check if a function is disabled
isDisabled() {
  local functionName="$1"
  for disabledFunction in "${disable_functions_array[@]}"; do
    if [ "$disabledFunction" == "$functionName" ]; then
      echo "true"
      return
    fi
  done
  echo "false"
}

# Define function_list variable based on deployment_slot
if [ "$deployment_slot" = "production" ]; then
  # Get the list of function names for the main slot (production)
  function_list=$(az rest --method get --uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/${functionAppName}/functions?api-version=2018-11-01" | jq -r '.value[].name' | cut -d '/' -f2)
else
  # Get the list of function names for the specified deployment slot
  function_list=$(az rest --method get --uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/${functionAppName}/slots/${deployment_slot}/functions?api-version=2018-11-01" | jq -r '.value[].name' | cut -d '/' -f2)
fi

# Transform disable_functions into an array
IFS=',' read -ra disable_functions_array <<< "$disable_functions"

# Loop through function names and disable/enable functions
for function in $function_list; do 
  isDisabledFlag=$(isDisabled "$function")
  if [ "$deployment_slot" = "production" ]; then
    az functionapp config appsettings set --name "$functionAppName" --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" --settings "AzureWebJobs.$function.Disabled=$isDisabledFlag"
  else
    az functionapp config appsettings set --name "$functionAppName" --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" --slot "$deployment_slot" --settings "AzureWebJobs.$function.Disabled=$isDisabledFlag"
  fi
done


# Check for non-existent functions in the disable_functions array compared to function_list
nonExistentFunctions=()
for disabledFunction in "${disable_functions_array[@]}"; do
 found=false
 for function_name in $function_list; do
 if [ "$disabledFunction" = "$function_name" ]; then
  found=true
  break
 fi
 done
 if [ "$found" = false ]; then
 nonExistentFunctions+=("$disabledFunction")
 fi
done

# Output non-existent functions and exit if any are found
if [ ${#nonExistentFunctions[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
 printf -v joined '%s, ' "${nonExistentFunctions[@]}"
 echo "Error: The following functions do not exist: ${joined%, }" >&2
 exit 1
fi
```

**Powershell Script:**

```
# Retrieve a list of functions from an Azure Function App in a specific deployment slot
      $functions = func azure functionapp list-functions ${data.azurerm_linux_function_app.temp_function.name} --slot ${var.deployment_slot}
     
     # Extract the names of the functions from the list
      $functionNames = $functions | Select-String -Pattern '^\s+([^\s]+)\s+-' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
     
     # Get the list of functions to be disabled from an environment variable and store it in an $disable_functions
      $disable_functions = $env:TF_VAR_disable_functions -split "," | Where-Object { $_ -ne "" }

     # Compare the list of functions with disable function list, if matched, functions are disabled else functions are enabled
       foreach ($function in $functionNames) {
       $isDisabled = $disable_functions -contains $function
       az functionapp config appsettings set --name ${data.azurerm_linux_function_app.temp_function.name} --resource-group ${data.azurerm_resource_group.temp_rg.name} --slot ${var.deployment_slot} --settings "AzureWebJobs.$function.Disabled=$isDisabled"
      }

     # Throw an error if any non-existent functions were specified in the $disable_functions list
      $nonExistentFunctions = $disable_functions | Where-Object { $functionNames -notcontains $_ }
        if ($nonExistentFunctions.Count -gt 0) {
        throw "The following functions do not exist: $($nonExistentFunctions -join ', ')"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote a Terraform script to disable multiple functions in the Azure Function app and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

Certainly! Let's break down the requirements and tackle them one by one:

1. Deploy Azure Functions from a directory.
2. Have the ability to enable or disable individual functions based on the environment.

Terraform can manage the resources, but it can't natively make decisions on which functions to enable or disable based on some dynamic criteria. For this, we'd typically use a combination of Terraform variables and, possibly, local-exec provisioners or external data sources to execute scripts or other code to determine the desired state.

For the sake of simplicity, I'll show you a basic example of how you can use Terraform to deploy Azure Functions and control their state based on a variable.

**My terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "v-sakavya"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "demovlsbstorageaccountvk"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-appserviceplan"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  os_type             = "Windows"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "vksbfunctapp"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key

  site_config {}

  app_settings = {
    "AzureWebJobs.MyFunction.Disabled" = var.environment == "dev" ? "true" : "false"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_function_app_slot" "example" {
  name                       = "examplevksbslot"
  function_app_id            = azurerm_windows_function_app.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key

  site_config {
    always_on = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [site_config[0]]
  }
}
```

For controlling the function state, In general, we do this at the level of the function key or the function app settings. For example, you could use the `app_settings` of the `azurerm_function_app` resource to control a function's state.

Let's say you have a function called `MyFunction`. If you want to disable it in the `dev` environment, enable it in the `prod` environment.

##### variable.tf:

```
variable "environment" {
  description = "The deployment environment (e.g., prod, dev)"
  type        = string
}
```

##### output.tf:

```
output "function_app_url" {
  value = azurerm_windows_function_app.example.default_hostname
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Repeat the same with **prod** so that it disables the functions we require as mentioned in the query.

Comment: Thanks fo the update. I would like to call the function names from the Json file's which are in a directory for ex: functions is a directory where we have 10 function folders and each function is having json file. Client is asking if we can add any attribute or flag in the json so that from the function level itself can we disable or enable it. Also, via terraform the way you showed me is hardcoding the function names but I don't want to hardcode function names instead I want to call those function names from the Json files which are in a functions directory. How to update the script

Comment: @PRAVEENPDBR without mentioning the total information in the query it's difficult to understand you're requirements. Please provide all the relevant info related to JSON and terraform code you tried along with the blockers (if you have any) will try to resolve the issue accordingly. Please provide the necessary info in the form of a new query.